# Delphi rounded-border button

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I am developing a game for a pretty important project and I need some buttons in my form. These buttons by the way must be round. I mean:

[image]

The picture show what I am looking for. I have found on the internet this procedure and people said that it works pretty well:

```
procedure DrawRounded(Control: TWinControl) ;
var
   R: TRect;
   Rgn: HRGN;
begin
   with Control do
   begin
     R := ClientRect;
     rgn := CreateRoundRectRgn(R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom, 20, 20) ;
     Perform(EM_GETRECT, 0, lParam(@r)) ;
     InflateRect(r, - 4, - 4) ;
     Perform(EM_SETRECTNP, 0, lParam(@r)) ;
     SetWindowRgn(Handle, rgn, True) ;
     Invalidate;
   end;
end;
```

So I wrote this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //code for other stuff

  DrawRounded(Button1);
end;
```

I am using Lazarus 1.2.4 at the moment. By the way, when I am going to compile, I have an error that says `Identifier not found "HRGN"`.

I thought that I had to include a library in the `uses` but I didn't find anything. Any help?

Comment: It's defined in [`lcltype.pp`](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lcltype/hrgn.html).

Comment: why the downvotes? At least comment instead of downvoting, seems to be happing far too frequently these days. We are not all as gifted as most around here so no matter how basic or trivial the question rather than just give negative downvotes at least explain what is wrong. I see no problem with this question but then I guess that might explain why I also get plenty of downvotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check of the source code reveals that `HRGN` is defined in `LCLType.pp`.

Add `LCLType` to the unit in question and the code should then compile.